# Evaluate .nb automatically and sequentially using external file as input

Tags: export, import, scripting, automation

I am interested in implemented the following workflow. I have a Mathematica script that receives an input (manually), executes the algorithm based on that input, and stores output into a CSV file. Then I manually change input, re-run my script (with clear cache) and store my results in the same CSV file as previously, but into a new line.
My question is this:

Let’s say that I have an excel or CSV file, that has all input data I need to evaluate, each into a different line. Is there any way to:

1. Open my input list (file).
2. Go to line 1
3. Use this input in my script
4. Execute script
5. Store output in CSV file line 1.
6. (restart process) Open input list
7. Go to line 2
8. Use this input in muy script
9. Execute script
10. Store output in CSV file line 2.
11. Etc

N-step. Once input list has ended terminate loop

To give you a better illustration of what I am trying to achieve, here is a dummy script that reflects the complexity of what I need to achieve, along with my input list (CSV file).
My goal is to be able to run eventually a much larger script, for approximately 1800 times. I managed to find how to store my results automatically with the help of the [community](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132895/run-nb-file-and-export-each-time-in-new-line-of-the-same-xls-file), but I cannot figure out how/if to overcome the input process.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

file=OpenAppend["output.csv"];

x1=3;
x2=1.1;
f[x_]:=PDF[PoissonDistribution[2.5],x];
g[y_]:=PDF[ExponentialDistribution[1.2],y]
data={{x1,x2,f[x1],g[x2],f[x1]*g[x2]}};

Export[file,data,"CSV"];
WriteString[file,"\n"];

Close[file];
```

While [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfzlqdc4rczbain/input.csv?dl=0) you can find my input CSV file. In this file there are several lines, each of them has 2 numbers, that refer to `x1` and `x2` in my given script.

My idea, but I am still trying to figoure out how to implement it is:

- To set a counter for each evaluation starting from 1 (outside my clear all statement which is crucial in my original script).
- Import my input csv file, feed it into a table.
- Ask x1 and x2 to receive values from line dictated by my counter (step 1) and columns 1 and 2 respectively.
- execute script.
- store output.csv.
- automatically rerun the whole script.

Comment: Don't write *scripts*. It's not the usual way to use Mathematica. Encapsulate the algorithm into a *function*, and call it with different parameters are many times as necessary. Also, don't do so many file manipulations unless you have a really huge input file that cannot be read into memory.  Instead: import all the data, `Map` your processing function to it, then export it in a single go. Useful functions: `Map`, `Table`, `MapIndexes`, `MapThread`, etc.

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right. My input is not complicated, only 5 variables. My only difficulty is in automating the procedure, so that I wont have to run it 1800 times, while each time I have to manually feed input. What I have done so far, is set a counter on the top of my algorithm, then clear cache apart from counter, and give `counter = counter + 1` before running it. At the same time, I import my input.csv, store it into a table, and feed my variables with corresponding line equal to `counter`. Doing that I have managed to automate my workflow into "1800 enters" for evaluating it.