# Exporting output from many NDSolve's to common .txt

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, export, data

Let there be the following working example

```
xo = 0/10;
yo = 10/10;
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == xo, y[0] == yo, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, root = t]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", WorkingPrecision -> 61, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

I know that with some code like

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Table[
   Flatten@{N[t, 25], N[(x[t] /. s), 25], N[(y[t] /. s), 25]}, {t, 
    N[0/10, 100], N[2*Pi, 100], N[1/1000, 100]}]; 
name = "xo=" <> ToString[CForm[xo]] <> "_yo=" <> ToString[CForm[yo]] <>
    ".txt";
Export[name, data, "TSV"];
```

I can store output from this single `NDSolve` to `.txt`.

However what if I need to store, say, several `root`'s  of `x` for many different `yo` and a particular `xo`?  My guess was

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data2 = Table[
   Flatten@{yo, N[root, 25], N[(y[root] /. s), 25]}, {t, 1, 1}]; 
name2 = "xo=" <> ToString[CForm[xo]] <> ".txt";
Export[name2, data2, "TSV"];
```

But then I am not sure how I could re-open `"xo=" <> ToString[CForm[xo]] <> ".txt"` and save another `root` for some other `yo`. Let alone iterate over `yo`.

**Update:** So this is a solution:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data2 = Table[
   Flatten@{N[yo, 25], N[root, 25], N[(y[root] /. s), 25]}, {t, 1, 1}];
name2 = "xo=" <> ToString[CForm[xo]] <> ".txt"; 
file = OpenAppend[name2]
string = ExportString[data2, "TSV"];
WriteString[file, string]
WriteString[file, "\n"];
Close[name2]
```

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2227/1871

Comment: Let me check that...

Comment: Well I am not exatly sure how this may fit my case. Working on it..

Comment: Ok, that was the solution. I added it as an update.