# How to save data to a new file, import the data and then use it

Tags: plotting, export, import, save

I have a for loop which generates random matrices and then some scalar numbers for example:

`For[j = 1, j <= 100, j++,a=RandomState[4];b=RandomState[4];c=Tr[a];d=Tr[b];e=b+c;{a,b,c,d,e}>>>file.csv] data=Import["file.csv path","Data"]`

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All,3]],data[[All,4]]]
```

I need to save this data to a new file and then import to plot for example c against d and perform some other numerical calculations. I have tried the above however it does not work. Here RandomState is from the QI package.

Comment: What is `>>>`? Why not use `Export`?

Comment: I just learned that `>>>` is equivalent to `PutAppend`. Either use `Export/Import` or `Put/Get`. And `Put` does not write in CSV format, it writes the `InputForm` of an expression. Check the documentation.

Comment: I think there is at least one [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2227/169) to this question. Can you check whether the answer to this question solves your problem?